# Badlion server crashes when I enter a game (while teleporting)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When i enter a game (while teleporting me) it crashes and says "packet 64 had too big of a size."

What is this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: [Badlion](https://www.badlion.net/) appears to be a minecraft mod. Hence, I'm flagging this question for closure as a modded minecraft crash.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about support for a modded version of Minecraft.

Answer (score 2):

After reinstalling Minecraft, the problem seemed to have fixed itself.